# Estimating maximum number of players winning a Tournament

Tags: combinatorics

In a tournament, there are $ 2n $ people, each of whom competes in $m $ 1 vs 1 rounds. In terms of $n$ and $m$ , determine the maximum number of people who can win more than half of the rounds they compete in.

My try:
consider that $k$ is the maximum number of person who win more than half of the matches, now i thought if some people win says $m/2 + 2 $ and some $m/2 + 1$ etc. then k attend different values, out of these maximum will be when each of these $k$ people win exactly $m/2+1$ matches. Also there are $mn$ total matches.
Now my strategy was to calculate/approximate total number of matches using the fact that k people win exactly $m/2+1$ matches. But these does not worked, can someone please tell me whats wrong in this reasoning and also if possible provide me with an hint. Thank you in advance.

Comment: The intuitive starting point is $\dfrac{mn}{\frac{m}{2}+1}$ when $m$ is odd and $\dfrac{mn}{\frac{m}{2}+2}$ when $m$ is even, in each case rounded down to an integer.  The difficult part is deciding whether this is the final answer or just an upper bound

Comment: Suppose $m$ is odd and $2n$ divisible by $m+2$, say $m=2k+1$ and $n=t(k+1)$. Then you can have $t$ losers and $2n-t=mt=\frac{2mn}{m+1}$ winners. Each of the $t$ losers loses all $m$ of his matches. Each winner wins one match against a loser. Each winner plays $m-1=2k$ matches against other winners and breaks even, winning $k$ and losing $k$, for a total score of $k+1$ wins and $k$ losses.

Comment: How can we say that each of these $t$ losers loses all m of his matches.

Comment: @KeshavSharma I don't understand your comment. I was just giving an example showing how it is possible (if some divisibility conditions are met) to have $\frac{2mn}{m+1}$ players winning more than half their matches. In this example, the remaining players lose all their matches. You don't think that's possible?

Comment: @bof Ok, sorry I thought that you were saying that there will always a loser (who loses all the matches).